# Visual Studio 2012 switch layout when build and run

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can anybody tell me how to keep the same layout when running as well as coding in visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start debugging it activates the "debug UI context". Every UI context can have UI elements assigned to it - that's why the layout changes.

In debugging mode just change the layout and make it exactly the same as when you are not debugging. The layout will be saved in this UI context.

Comment: thanks you. I will change it